# How to get numericupdown control to pass its value to a another control as I am typing not by having to hit Enter or click on another control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several numericupdown controls on a Winform. I have all the NUDs on the form coded to summarize all the NUDs inside a textbox. My issue is not with that, that happens perfectly. My issue is, that in order for the value from any of the NUDs to summarize inside the texbox, I have to either press enter or click inside any other NUD. Clicking on Tab will not work. I want the value inside the texbox to be updated as I type inside any of the NUDS, without having to press enter or give focus to another NUD. How can I do that? By the way, I've placed the code to summarize all the NUDs inside the ValueChanged event of each NUD. This is the code I have placed inside each NUD ValueChanged Event. Thank you

```
private void NudNumberOne_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NudNumberOne.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(NudNumberTwo.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(NudNumberThree.Text))
textBox1.Text = (double.Parse(NudNumberOne.Text) + double.Parse(NudNumberTwo.Text) + double.Parse(NudNumberThree.Text)).ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValueChanged()` event doesn't fire until the Text value has been parsed successfully into a numeric value and assigned to the NumericUpDown control. You've already found that this doesn't happen until you hit Enter or change controls.

The NumericUpDown doesn't expose a `TextChanged()` event...but it's easy enough to cast it back to `Control` and wire it up that way.  Just do this in the `Load()` event of your Form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)NudNumberOne).TextChanged += Ctl_TextChanged;
    ((Control)NudNumberTwo).TextChanged += Ctl_TextChanged;
    ((Control)NudNumberThree).TextChanged += Ctl_TextChanged;
}

private void Ctl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        textBox1.Text = (double.Parse(NudNumberOne.Text) + double.Parse(NudNumberTwo.Text) + double.Parse(NudNumberThree.Text)).ToString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the second time in an hour I've seen you suggest this "trick". Brilliant. Added to my toolbox.

Comment: "The numeric updown class doesn't expose a TextChanged event" Are you sure? [How about NumericUpdown.TextChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.textchanged?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse, Note the `[System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]` attribute for that event.  That means it won't get listed in the Events for the NumericUpDown through the Properties Pane, nor when you try to wire it up directly via code (at least through Visual Studio).  Drop a NumericUpDown control on a WinForms form and report back your findings.  Yes, it is technically exposed via the class, and you can still wire it up directly via code without error, but many people wouldn't think to do so since it doesn't appear with IntelliSense.

Comment: The numericupdown control doesn't have a TextChanged event it has a ValueChanged event and the answer from Idle_Mind fixed my problem.

Comment: Thank you Idle_Mind your answer worked like a charm. Now I have to figure out how to get a label thats associated to the NUD to change its value as the value in the numericupdown gets changed by the user. Because right now the value inside the label only changes when I press enter or tab or take focus away from the numericupdown associated to that label.

Comment: You can add the code to change the associated label right there inside the `try` part of the code above.  If need some help with that part, give me more details.